# Missing port when starting Rails with Foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

I am new to RoR and I am trying to install specific project. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and I trying to run the project from terminal. I have already installed all needed gems following project's specifications.

**Issue**

When I run this command which is trying to run the project

```
foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

It gives me the following error

```
17:01:33 web.1    | started with pid 4538
17:01:33 worker.1 | started with pid 4540
17:01:34 web.1    | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:33:in `parse!': missing argument: --port (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
17:01:34 web.1    |     from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:293:in `parse_options'
17:01:34 web.1    |     from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:184:in `options'
17:01:34 web.1    |     from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:58:in `set_environment'
17:01:34 web.1    |     from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:42:in `initialize'
17:01:34 web.1    |     from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `new'
17:01:34 web.1    |     from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
17:01:34 web.1    |     from bin/rails:4:in `require'
17:01:34 web.1    |     from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
17:01:34 web.1    | exited with code 1
17:01:34 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
17:01:34 worker.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
```

This is what I have in Procfile.dev:

```
web: bundle exec rails s --port $DEV_PORT
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
# exec: lt --port $DEV_PORT --subdomain $SUBDOMAIN
```

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: just add foreman start -f Procfile.dev -p 2000

Answer (score 0):

Foreman sets up an environment variable called `$PORT`, not `$DEV_PORT`. Unless you've set up `$DEV_PORT` yourself (which won't work if you need to deploy somewhere like Heroku), you're explicitly starting your processes with an empty port. Change your Procfile to use `$PORT` and you should be good to go.